# histogram.cpp:3915: error: (-215) _src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function cv::equalizeHist

Tags: python, opencv

```
files2 = [f for f in listdir(dstpath) if isfile(join(dstpath,f))]        
for image in files2:
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dstpath,image))
    equ = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    dstPath2 = join(dstpath,image)
    cv2.imwrite(dstPath2,equ)
```

I have a folder consisting of grayscale images in jpg format but when I run my above code for Histogram equalization it gives me the above mentioned error. Pls help

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit the question accordingly. Part of that would be to give an understandable title and including the full traceback in the question body.

Comment: Using yr debugging tool verify if image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`imread` load image in color mode by default. Try to use `img = cv2.imread(your_image_path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` instead

Comment: Now it doesn't even convert the original image to grayscale

Answer (score 0):

```
@author: Quantum
"""
import cv2
import os
from os import listdir,makedirs
from os.path import isfile,join


path = r'' # Source Folder
dstpath = r'' # Destination Folder


try:
    makedirs(dstpath)
except:
    print ("Directory already exist, images will be written in asme folder")

# Folder won't used
files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path,f))] 

for image in files:
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,image),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        **imgnew=cv2.equalizeHist(img)**
        dstPath = join(dstpath,image)
        cv2.imwrite(dstPath,imgnew)
    except:
        print ("{} is not converted".format(image))
```

All I did was added the histeq function while my files are converted to grayscale